# Testing Threads with Junits

Tags: java, multithreading, junit

I have code that calls another thread and business logic is in that run() method. 
ex code:

```
public class Test {
    protected boolean stripObjects ;
    protected boolean catcharchiveObjects 
    public void runZipper(boolean strip,boolean createarchive) {        
        stripObjects = strip;
        catcharchiveObjects = createcatcharchive; 
        exThread czct = new exThread();        
        czct.start();        
    }

    private class exThread extends Thread() {
         public void run() {
         try {                                          
             if (strip)
                return;
              if(checkAction())
              {
                ....
              }
             //some business logic which generates a zipfile
            }
         catch (Exception e) {
          }
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote Junit for the above code like Below.

```
public class JunitTest {
    public void testRunZipper() {
        Test testEx = new Test();
        testEx.runZipper(false,true);
        //assert statement to check whether zip file is created
    }
 }
```

When I run the Junit testcase it fails and zip is not generated.

Then I ran the Junit in debug mode and I see when czct.start() is called it goes to run method. But it immediately returned to calling function ie runZipper().

Now I modified the run() to add sysout as first statement in it. Now when I run Junit it prints whatever there in sysout and then control comes back to runZipper().

Can anyone help me out in solving this so that it executes all the statements in the run().

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? You're talking about a lot of things that don't appear in code.

Comment: I do not know how it could be, they work fine in my PC

Comment: I have modified my question. Hope it helps. But I am sorry I cant give compilable code and whole details as it is very big and confidential too.

Comment: I guess you are facing issue of thread synchronization. Your thread which creates zip file is spawn separately and your other code executes sequentially. I think, this causes your assert statement executed before zip is created completely. Try using wait or join to ensure that thread execution is complete and you have zip file created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add "watchers" into the code of classes that do any kind of multi-threading processing while still require unit-testing. The idea is: after every logical step class send a signal to the watcher. Typically in prod environment, there is no-one observing these signals, while in unit-test env or functional tests env you would add a watcher with a time bounded latch.

Here is an example

```
public class MultithreadingInUnitTest {
    private Watcher watcher = new DefaultWatcher();

    public void runZipper() {
        exThread czct = new exThread();
        watcher.process(WatchedEvent.EVENT_1);
        czct.start();
    }

    private class exThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                //some business logic which generates a zipfile
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {
                watcher.process(WatchedEvent.EVENT_2);
            }
        }
    }


    public void setWatcher(Watcher watcher) {
        this.watcher = watcher;
    }

    private class DefaultWatcher implements Watcher {
        @Override
        public void process(WatchedEvent event) {
            //Noop for production use
        }
    }
}

interface Watcher {
    public void process(WatchedEvent event);
}

enum WatchedEvent {
    EVENT_1, EVENT_2
}
```

This is how you unit-test it. Note time limit of the latch

```
class JunitTest {
    public void testRunZipper() throws InterruptedException {
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        Watcher watcher = new Watcher() {
            @Override
            public void process(WatchedEvent event) {
                if (event == WatchedEvent.EVENT_2) { latch.countDown(); }
            }
        };
        MultithreadingInUnitTest testEx = new MultithreadingInUnitTest();
        testEx.setWatcher(watcher);

        testEx.runZipper();
        latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (latch.getCount() != 0) { Assert.fail("Latch was never triggered"); }

        //assert statement to check whether zip file is created
    }

}
```